# Titanium- Post request is not working when I using JSONArray in body content

Tags: post, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile

Hi I am sending POST request using HTTPClient. Here I am passing some JSON data which have some arrays.

```
 {
      "pccpId": "11111",
      "courseId": "XXXXX",
      "employeeId": "XXXXXX",
      "userId": "X!@#$",
      "assignments": [
        {
          "Id": "XXXX",
          "targetDate": "05/30/2018",
          "targetNewDate": "04/30/2018"
        },
        {
          "Id": "YYYYY",
          "targetDate": "04/22/2018",
          "targetNewDate": "04/26/2018"
        }
      ]
    }
```

When I am using this data, I am getting 400 error code. When I am checking with backend is not at all hitting to the server. Same data giving expected result when I run on Postman.

Anyone have any suggestion!!

Thanks

Comment: Could be helpful if you post some code examples of what you are doing...

Comment: It might be content-type issue. If u can share code or share screenshot of postman.

Answer (score 0):

I have this pb with titanium nodeJS api, workaround is to stringify your data and parse it on server

Comment: Waste of compute time to serialize the data. Best way is to get the object as intended on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to but your keys without double quotation like this

```
{
  pccpId: "11111",
  courseId: "XXXXX",
  employeeId: "XXXXXX",
  userId: "X!@#$",
  assignments: [{
      "Id": "XXXX",
      "targetDate": "05/30/2018",
      "targetNewDate": "04/30/2018"
    },
    {
      "Id": "YYYYY",
      "targetDate": "04/22/2018",
      "targetNewDate": "04/26/2018"
    }
  ]
}
```